# How to uninstall Xcode 4.5 from my MacBook?

Tags: osx-lion, xcode4.5

I have installed Xcode 4.5 to my mac system. Now I need to uninstall Xcode 4.5 and install Xcode 4.2.

How to uninstall Xcode 4.5 from my system?

Comment: All mighty google give me the answer: http://osxdaily.com/2012/02/20/uninstall-xcode/ - note you do not have to chant to get an answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[How to Uninstall XCode.](http://osxdaily.com/2012/02/20/uninstall-xcode)

[How to have multiple Versions of XCode](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/xcode/download-and-install-older-versions-of-xcode-xcode-previous-releases.html)

All from a quick google search!

And before you ask ["Where to find older versions of Xcode"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839526/where-to-download-older-xcode-versions)